# copy a div to a window popup with css

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to take a div and basically put it in a child window. The domains are going to be the same so I figure I could do the flowing ( where parm win is the div ).

```
popOut = function ( win )
    {
        var newWindow = window.open( "about:blank", "", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400", false );

        newWindow.onload = function () 
        {
            this.focus
            this.document.body.appendChild( win );
        };

    }
```

This seems to do the job but the css is clobbered. In thinking about this, the new window certainly knows nothing of the includes and css files. Can I copy or inject this info over somehow?

Would I be correct in assuming the new window knows nothing of its parent, thus no function can be ran from child to parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New window is definitely aware of its opener as well as opener aware of the popup. If the problem is new window not seeing opener styles, the following code should copy styles from opener to popup.

Place this after `var newWindow = window.open(...)`

```
var linkrels = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

for (var i = 0, max = linkrels.length; i < max; i++) {

    if (linkrels[i].rel && linkrels[i].rel == 'stylesheet') {

      var thestyle = document.createElement('link');
      var attrib = linkrels[i].attributes;
      for (var j = 0, attribmax = attrib.length; j < attribmax; j++) {
         thestyle.setAttribute(attrib[j].nodeName, attrib[j].nodeValue);
      }
      newWindow.document.documentElement.appendChild(thestyle);

   }
}
```

I haven't got a chance to test it, but something like this should work.

Comment: I see the concept here but something is not right. You said "Place this after" but you are using newWindow so it cant be after? Do I need to store this in a temp var?

Comment: hmm I guess I could push them all on an array and open the window then loop that array adding them back? I'll test this why I await the reply. -- yup, that did it. --

Comment: Yes I mean place the code after `var newWindow = window.open(...)`. First you create `newWindow` variable and then the code uses it to create LINK elements

Comment: Ok I see, I read that backwards. Also do I need to do something similar for window events?

Comment: Not really, you just need to copy styles used by your DIV. Verify popup in Dev tools that it has `<link>` elements created

Comment: oh wow this is crazy, of I see what is going on and it makes perfect sense but is there a way to fix this?  The child window responds to the parents events. What I have here is a div in the child window that was created by the parent window and events on the parent resize the div if window.resize is invoked. Naturally I need the events remapped to the new window. I would need to re do the event and some how ignore parent events, I think?

Comment: Ok I believe I got it, Ill have to proto type the events for the new window. Getting to proprietary at this point. Thx for the help.